# On primes of the form 2^n + k

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For any odd number $k$, can we always find an $n$ so that $2^n > k$ and $2^n + k$ is a prime number?

Any comment or remark is welcomed!

Comment: No. Erdos showed that $2^n+9262111$ is never prime. See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5323/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-2nc-as-n-varies.

Comment: Not that one: $2^{104} + 9262111 = 20282409603651670423947260548127$ is prime.  But ISTR there was some number...

Comment: It would work for $1001018989$, since $2^n + 1001018989$ is always divisible by at least one of $3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 37, 73$.  But what was the number Erdős found?

Comment: Counterexamples to this claim are called dual Sierpinski numbers, and the smallest is believed to be 78557.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number  It seems the number 9262111 originates from some slides of Pomerance which contain a numerical error in the application of the Chinese remainder theorem.  I think Erdos solved a slightly different problem (locating an arithmetic progression which contained no numbers of the form $p+2^n$) - it seems it was Selfridge who first produced a Sierpinski number.

Comment: The result of Erdos is Theorem 3 of https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf which as Terry points out is a result about APs.

Comment: Wow -- that answer at the 2009 thread has sat there with the 9262111 for over 6 years and nobody (including me) bothered to check. Thanks very much Robert!

Comment: FWIW the correct solution to the congruences in the Pomerance slides is $k=1518781$, which is in the list of known Sierpinski numbers on Wikipedia, but apparently the Sierpinski numbers are conjectured to be the same as the dual Sierpinski numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Now we know the claim is false. If it were true, then we would be able to write an infinite string in base 2, starting with 11, so that every initial segment gives us a prime number (in base 2). Here is a related question QUESTION: is there a base b, and an infinite string in base b so that every initial segment gives us a prime number?