# Do Sierpiński numbers of Izotov type have a covering set?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

[Sierpiński number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) is an odd integer $k$ such that $2^nk+1$ is composite for all $n\in{\mathbb N}$. In the paper [Sur un probleme concernant les nombres $k\cdot2^n+1$](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=edm-001:1960:15#133), zbl:0093.04602 (1960), Sierpiński proved that there are infinitely many $k$ with this property. All integers $2^nk+1$ constructed by Sierpiński are divisible by at least one of the primes in an explicit small set (a [covering set](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=SierpinskiNumber)).

Then, in [A note on Sierpinski numbers](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/33-3/izotov.pdf), zbl:0849.11016 (1995), Izotov has given infinitely many Sierpiński numbers of a new type $(*)$:

- for $n=4m+2$, the number $2^nk+1$ has an easy algebraic factorization;
- for all other $n$, the number $2^nk+1$ is divisible by at least one of the primes $\{3,17,257,641,65537,6700417\}$ (a covering set).

(The author notes that the above covering set does *not* work when $n=4m+2$.)

Two decades later, in the paper [Sierpiński and Carmichael numbers](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/BFLPST_AMS121001.pdf), zbl:1325.11010 (2015), 
Banks et al. write:

> **Every** currently known Sierpiński number $k$ possesses at least one covering set $\cal P$,
>   which is a finite set of prime numbers with the property that $2^nk+1$ is divisible
>   by some prime in $\cal P$ for every $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

So, for Sierpiński numbers of the Izotov type $(*)$, was a bigger covering set found between 1995 and 2015?

Comment: Related: [Primes in a shifted geometric sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337598/).

Comment: Full reference: W.Banks, C.Finch, F.Luca, C.Pomerance, P.Stănică, [Sierpiński and Carmichael numbers](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1325.11010). Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 367, No. 1, 355-376 (2015).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683082/does-every-sierpinski-number-have-a-finite-congruence-covering where the question of Sierpinski without covering was discussed (but not settled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, for Sierpiński numbers of the Izotov type $(*)$, was
> a bigger covering set found between 1995 and 2015?

No, it was not. And it is conjectured that none exists. In the Math Stack Exchange thread linked by Gerry Myerson in a comment to the question, I give other examples of Sierpiński numbers for which it is not likely that they should possess such a covering set $\cal P$.

(I do not know why Banks et al. repeated the obsolete claim that all known Sierpiński numbers possess a covering.)