# Prime numbers of the form $P^x+C$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let it be $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers. Let it be $p\in\mathbb{P}$ some prime number, and $C$ some fixed constant such that $p+C\in\mathbb{P}$. One might wonder if there exist infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^{x}+C\in\mathbb{P}$.

For instance, taking $p=2$, and noticing that $2+1\in\mathbb{P}$, it might be wondered if there exist infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$. Until today, this particular case remains unanswered, because if is known that  $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$ only if $x$ is of the form $x=2^n$, but it is not known if there exist infinite values of $x$ of the form $x=2^n$ such that $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$ (that is, it is not know if there exist infinitely many Fermat primes).

I am interested in known general results regarding this problem (if any).

Thanks in advance!

(This question is also posted in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134231/prime-numbers-of-the-form-pxc), but got no answer and very few comments)

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/q/5323/30186

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for the reference!

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/a/337610/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev nice reference too, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primes in shifted geometric sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337598/primes-in-shifted-geometric-sequence)

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev thanks for the reference! The post you share has similarities, but it does not answer the question, which asks for the state of the art of a different conjecture.