# Modular parametrization abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer, and let $f$ be a newform for $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$. Then by Shimura's construction, the variety $J_0(N)$ has a quotient $A_f$ which is an abelian variety attaced to $f$.
$$\pi:J_0(N) \to A_f$$
Dualizing this map we get a map $A_f^\vee \to J_0(N)^\vee$, and since the latter is isomorphic to $J_0(N)$ (it is a Jacobian), we get a map
$$A_f^\vee \to A_f$$
This map is an isogeny of degree $d^2$ for some positive integer $d$, and the modular degree is defined precisely as $d$. The curve $X_0(N)$ has a natural inclusion into its Jacobian, so it make sence to look at the map
$$ X_0(N) \hookrightarrow J_0(N) \to A_f$$
Question: is any relation between the degree of the map $X_0(N) \to A_f$ (which I mean the degree of $X_0(N)$ onto its image) and $d$? I would guess that to prove an inequality should not be that hard, but is it an equality? (in the case $A_f$ has dimension $1$ it is)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\tau : X_0(N) \to A_f$ be the name of your map. And let $C := \tau(X_0(N))$ then if $A_f \cong J(C)$ and furthermore the inclusion $C \subseteq A_f$ can be identified with the Abel-Jacobi map, then the relation you are asking for does hold. This just stems from a more general fact of maps between curves, namely if $g: X \to Y$ is a map of curves then the composition of pullback and pushforward $J(Y) \to J(X) \to J(Y)$ is just multiplication by $\deg g$. So there is a relation this case, namely
$$\text{deg }( A_f^\vee \to A_f) = (\text{deg }X_0(N) \to C)^{2 genus(C)}.$$
So the same formula holds except that you have to include the genus of the image curve.

However in general I do not expect such a relation to hold. To give an explicit counter example, if $N=311$ then according to the [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/?hst=List&level_type=prime&level=311&weight=2&char_order=1&search_type=List) there are only two (galois orbits of) newforms. Namely $f_a := 311.2.a$ and $f_b := 311.2.b$. Now consider the map $\pi_b: X_0(N) \to A_{f_b}$. Since $A_{f_b}$ is a simple abelian variety of dimension $22$ any curve inside $A_{f_b}$ has to have genus $\geq 22$. In particular $C := \pi_b(X_0(N))$ has to have genus $\geq 22$. However $genus(X_0(311))=26$ so the riemann hurwitz formula forces deg$(\pi_b)=1$. However $$\text{deg }( A_{f_b}^\vee \to A_{f_b}) = \text{deg }( A_{f_a}^\vee \to A_{f_a}) = 2^{2genus(X_0(N)^+)}=2^{8}$$
So in this case there is no relation of the form you want. See section 3.4 of [these lecture notes](https://wstein.org/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/11-14-03/11-14-03.pdf) for the first equality.

Note that the above is not an isolated or pathological example. There are [many more examples in the LFMDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/?hst=List&level_type=prime&level=2100-&weight=2&char_order=1&search_type=List) where $N$ is prime and there are only 2 galois orbits of newforms in $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ and in all these cases a similar argument works to show there is no interesting relation between the degrees for the modular form whose Fricke sign is $-1$. Aside from the LMFDB examples this situation is also something that is conjectured to happen quite often (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/396522/23501).

Answer (score -2):

The degree of the map is the modular degree.  This is Lemma 5.2 of [Component Groups of Purely Toric Quotients by Stein and Conrad](http://wstein.org/papers/compgrp/compgrp.pdf).  The idea is to examine the size of the kernel of the map.