# How often is the rank of J_0(p)^- zero

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, abelian-varieties, jacobians

As mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/396522/23501) there is a conjecture by 
[Kimball Martin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06911.pdf) that, formulated slightly informally, has the following special case.

**Conjecture:**
On average $J_0(p)$ has 2 simple components when  $p$ varies over all primes.

This conjecture then also leads us to expect that $J_0(p)^-$ is simple most of the time. Additionally we know that $J_0(p)^-$ always has a positive dimensional rank 0 quotient when $p >> 0$, which leads to the conclusion that under this conjecture we should expect to have a lot of values of $p$ for which $J_0(p)^-$ has rank 0.

So my question is what do we know without assuming any conjectures in a possibly weaker form:

> Are there infinitely many primes $p$ for which $J_0(p)^-$ is simple.

and:

> Are there infinitely many primes $p$ for which $J_0(p)^-$ has rank 0.

Comment: You use irreducible to mean indescomposable, which I find a bit confusing. You conjecture then that for infinitely many primes $p$ the quocient $J_0(p)^-$ is equal to the winding quocient? May be Merel's methods could be use to study this question.

Comment: Sorry fixed the terminology. I'm actually quite familiar with Merels method, and the improvements on it by Oesterle and Parent. And I don't think that their methods for studying the winding quotient can be used to tackle this. They only give you lower bounds on the size of the winding quotient, and these bounds don't even have the right asymptotic growth rate. One of the reasons I was asking is actually the other way around. I was hoping to improve Merel and Oesterle's bounds in the uniform boundedness theorem, by having a better understanding of the winding quotient.